# StackOverflowException on LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, stack-overflow

I have a LinQ query which is creating a `StackOverflowException`.

Code:

```
class a
{
    string b;
}

List<a> s;
```

I am trying to select the distinct `b` in alphabetical order.

```
(from a in s select a.b).Distinct().OrderBy(b => b);
```

Comment: Put together a small but complete sample to test on

Comment: Do you have more code where you for example initialize the List and place the query in a variable?

Comment: No, you don't, or at least not there. There you could have a compilation error of `'a.b' is inaccessible due to its protection level`.

Comment: I highly recommend that you post the original code you tried running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your code is like this:

```
class a
{
    private string _b;

    public string b
    {
        get 
        {
            return b; // <-- ERROR! Must be _b
        }

        set
        {
            _b = value;
        }
    }
}
```

The other "most common" is a recursive comparator for `b`. But if `b` is a `string`, this option doesn't exist.